# Permantly ban a WIFI network on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration

I ran this following command attempting to permanently block my computer from connecting to Comcast/Xfinity wireless networks:

```
netsh wlan add filter permission=block ssid=xfinitywifi
```

I received the following error:

> One or more parameters for the command are not correct or missing.

How do I prevent my computer from even connecting to this specific Xfinity wireless network?

Comment: You CAN tell Windows to only connect to networks you've configured. Have you tried this? Is there an app on your computer configuring it for Xfinity connection that you can remove? It just seems to my you're trying to use heavy artillery to "fix" something that really just needs a small hammer.

Comment: @music2myear As usual someone *else* edited my question and completely changed the context. See my comment in regards to the accepted answer.

Comment: @John - Only some not very nice language, and meta-commentary, was removed from your question.

Comment: @John I am the one who edited your question, removing unprofessional language and unnecessary non-context that distracted from the question itself. Networks are identified to your computer by the SSID. If the devices have the same controller (Xfinitywifi networks all connect to the same controller) your computer will, more or less, assume they are the same network. But, your further response make me more certain that you have installed on your computer a program that is telling your device to connect to Xfinity wifi, and THAT is the root problem you need to find and address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the error message I get if I try your command, then `networktype` is needed. So try:

```
netsh wlan add filter permission=block ssid=xfinitywifi networktype=infrastructure
```

Comment: Great, that worked in the immediate. Will this prevent the laptop from connecting to *all* routers named "xfinitywifi"?